# Нет доступка к сайту с Европы

Tags: apache, apache2, vps

Когда пытаюсь подключиться к сайту с Европы (через ВПН) выдаёт следующую ошибку:

It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Многие пишут, что дело в настройках апача, но нигде не могу найти инфу почему это может возникать именно при подключении с европы. Дело не в .htacces проверяли.

В чём может быть проблема и как это устранить.
Сайт Avtoday.com.ua

Comment: Нормально подключается

Comment: http://avtoday.com.ua.prx.nl.teleportyou.com/

Comment: Что это - как я должен догадаться?